# Let $g :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y) = (x,y+g(x))$. Show that $f$ is homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $g :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y) = (x,y+g(x))$. Show that $f$ is homeomorphic.

I got an advice that I should define $f$ as $f(z) = z+ g(\operatorname{pr_{1}(z))e_2}$, but I don't see how $f$ can be defined as such?

If I let $h(x,y)=(x,y-g(x))$ I have $$(h\circ f)(x,y)=h(x,y+g(x))=(x,y)$$ and $$(f\circ g)(x,y) = f(x,y-g(x)) = (x,y)$$

so and since $f$ and $h$ are both continuous bijections $f$ would be homeomorphic?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: "...but I don't see how $f$ can be defined as such?" Well, $$f(x,y) = (x,y)+(0,g(x)) = (x,y) + g(x)(0,1) = (x,y) + g(\operatorname{pr}_1(x,y))(0,1).$$

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is more clear, as long as you can show both $f$ and $h$ are continuos and bijections!

To see how $f(x,y)=f(z)$, it is pretty straightforward.  Note that $pr_1(z)=pr_1(x,y)=x$, so:
$$f(z) = z + g(pr_1(z))e_2 = z + g(x)e_2 = (x,y) + (0,g(x)) = (x,y+g(x)) = f(x,y) $$

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume that $g$ is continuous. Write $h(x)=(x,y-g(x))$ it is the inverse of $f$.